# Create a correlation between different point dataset

Tags: point, clustering, kernel-density, variable-kernel

I have different point data-sets in my map in ArcMap, but I am wondering if there is an tool in ArcMap that can analyze the correlation between the different data-sets.

Specifically, I need to know if there are areas on my map that have significant clustering of multiple point-datasets. Kernel density works fine if I want to see areas of density from one point-dataset, however, the kernel density will not allow me to see areas of density from multiple.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What correlation are you looking for between the datasets? When it is spatial autocorrelation you find a lot of tools in the Spatial Analyst. The problem is they do work for one dataset as you stated. You actually want to have a correlation for another correlation (your kernel density). In my opinion it can be done by either merging the datasets and use the output for a spatial query back to your single-datasets or you calculate the mean coordinates for your datasets and use them for a correlation.

Comment: Thanks, a spatial query back to my single dataset might work. Another question though, are there any possibilities to get the kernel density symbology to look like distance bands (black lines) instead of degrees, or variations of color?